# CallObjectMethod JNI playing with device backlight instead of running function

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, ndk-build

I am creating a native code to encrypt and decrypt data using JNI. I am using Java code to actually encrypt and decrypt, so I am calling those functions from cpp file.
The main activity calls this **encrypt** function passing the data as a byte array, and gets encrypted byte array in return.

When I am running the android app on the device, it just plays with backlight a little and quits. I tried commenting lines of code and the **CallObjectMethod()** is resulting in that behaviour.

This is the cpp code I am using.

```
JNIEXPORT jbyteArray JNICALL
Java_com_airtel_agilelabs_utils_NativeEncryptionUtils_encrypt(
    JNIEnv* env,
    jobject obj, jobject context, jbyteArray data) {
jbyteArray a = data;
jstring key = env->NewStringUTF("[key]");
jclass des = env->FindClass("com/test/test1/utils/NativeDES");
jmethodID encrypt_func = env->GetMethodID(des,"encryptdata","([BLjava/lang/String;)[B");
jobject result = env->CallObjectMethod(obj,encrypt_func,a,key);
jbyteArray byte_result = (jbyteArray) result;
return byte_result;
```

The java class to be called for the same is this

```
  public byte[] encryptdata(byte[] data1, String key)
  {
    byte[] clear = null;
    try {
        SecretKeySpec sc = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes("UTF-8"),"DESede");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DESede");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE,sc);
        clear = cipher.doFinal(data1);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return clear;
     }
```

Moreover, I am not sure if I have to use CallObjectMethod or any other function. The java function is returning a byte array, so I typecast the object. But since the error is arising on the previous step, so not sure if that works fine.

Comment: What's the point of this native function if all it does it call a bunch of Java methods? If you thought your key is safe because it's stored in native code then you're mistaken. Also, is there any particular reason why 3DES was selected instead of AES? As for your problem: the first step would be to fix the total lack of error checking, i.e. verify the result of each function call and that no exceptions have been thrown.

Comment: Michael, 3DES is requirement , as it is being used at server end for our app and I have to perform other tasks as well along with encryption in native code. Plus, for java I have implemented proper error handling, I just did not post that here, and the function is working fine on its own.

Comment: I meant error handling in the native code.

Comment: I am new to JNI, so I do not know much about it. But, the application is not crashing. It opens, turns the backlight on and off 2-3 times, and then quits(not crashes). I checked in logs, it shows something regarding output backlight and memory addresses

Comment: _"and then quits"_ Is it supposed to quit on its own? If not, then it sounds like it is crashing. If your app is shutting down unexpectedly you should analyze any logs/stacktraces that you're getting, and/or run the app with a debugger attached. And you really need to check for errors in your native code (see [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html) for more info). Don't just assume that everything will succeed.

Comment: Could you post the Java code which calls the native code?